# How to install ogre-meshviewer?

Tags: 20.04, 3d

I'm trying to install `ogre-meshviewer`, but I get the following error:

```
(base) comp@comp:~$ sudo snap install ogre-meshviewer
snap "ogre-meshviewer" is already installed, see 'snap help
              refresh'
(base) comp@comp:~$ 
(base) comp@comp:~$ sudo ogre-meshviewer
mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
usage: ogre_mesh_viewer.py [-h] [-c RESCFG] infile
ogre_mesh_viewer.py: error: the following arguments are required: infile
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the output of the `sudo snap install ogre-meshviewer` command informs you, `ogre-meshviewer` is successfully installed.

The error you get is because you try to run `ogre-meshviewer` without the required positional argument `infile`, which is an input file:

> ```
> usage: ogre_mesh_viewer.py [-h] [-c RESCFG] infile
> ogre_mesh_viewer.py: error: the following arguments are required: infile
> ```

So, if you run it as:

```
ogre-meshviewer /path/to/mesh_file
```

it should work correctly.

`/path/to/mesh_file` is, as expected, the path to a `.mesh` file (or any other [supported format](https://snapcraft.io/ogre-meshviewer), i.e. `.obj`, `.ply` or `.fbx`) already existing in your system. The path can be either [absolute or relative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths).

Comment: and how to save in .mesh ?? Example it was `ogre-meshviewer /home/comp/blender/ogre/korpys.obj` became  `/home/comp/blender/ogre/korpys.mesh` ??

Comment: @timob256 I don't think that `ogre-meshviewer` has the ability to change the format of a file, for example from `.mesh` to `.obj`. As I understand it (I'm not familiar with it), it's just a viewer. You would need a different program to do that.